# Define method on multiple structs that implement the same interface

Tags: go

Take the following piece of code:

```
type A struct { … }
func (a *A) Attr() int { … }

type B struct { … }
func (b *B) Attr() int { … }

type I interface{
  Attr() int
}

func (m that implements I) Process() int {
  do something with m.Attr()
}

func main() {
  a := A{}
  a.Process()
  b := B{}
  b.Process()
}
```

Methods cannot be defined on interfaces so `m` cannot be of type `I`. I tried using anonymous fields on `A` and `B` but `Attr` is specific to the associated structs so it can't be implemented on an anonymous field.

I want to avoid copy/pasting the `Process()` method on `A` and `B` since it is exactly the same. I could simply define

```
func Process(m I) int { … }
```

instead but it's not very elegant.

How would you go about doing this the go way?

Comment: why `Process(m I) int ` is not elegant ?

Comment: A function that takes an interface is the idiomatic way to do it.

Comment: Everything doesn't have to be a method like in some other OOP languages (e.g. Ruby).

Comment: Yes, I think I have to get rid of my OO reflexes ;-)

Comment: I agree that `func Process(m I) int { … }` seems to be the way to go. http://play.golang.org/p/t59t5KHlw6 .

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible in Go.  While you can introduce common methods to a number of types via embedding another type within a struct, those methods have no knowledge of the type they have been embedded in.

The usual Go idiom for this pattern is to use a function.  As an example, [`sort` package](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/) from the standard library.  It [defines an interface](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) consisting of the methods needed to implement a sort algorithm on a container (`Len`, `Less`, and `Swap`).  However, the actual sort algorithm [is exposed as a function](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort) that takes an argument implementing the interface.